# ALMOST THERE: Given an integer n, return True if n is within 10 of either 100 or 200

Tags: python, absolute-value

[image: Almost There questions]

How does "if n is within 10 of either 100 or 200" correlate with using the absolute value function?

I get what absolute value is, but wouldn't there be an easier/cleaner way without using abs()?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on which part you don't understand? Are you asking what the `abs` builtin does?

Comment: If they read the assignment text, the `abs` function is explained there.

Comment: Maybe it's the `or` operator that is the cause of the puzzlement?

Comment: My apologies, I will edit the post

Comment: Images of code are not acceptable on SO. Please see the [intro tour,](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) the [help center,](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and this post on [how to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @blorgon dont see anyone else having a problem with it

Comment: Don't count on it happening again. Had your question included code you were asking for help on, your post would've been closed until the issue was fixed. You were okay here as you were asking more of a conceptual question. It is **always** preferred that you provide code as copy-able text. It is **never** appropriate to include screenshots of code or error messages or data when asking for help on SO. BTW: you should accept Kirk's answer.

Comment: @JuanIsaacs I mean click on the check mark next to their post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure: you absolutely *could* (and I'd say *should*) write that like:

```
def almost_there(n):
    return 90 <= n <= 110 or 190 <= n <= 210
```

which I think more clearly communicates your intent to the next person who touches the code. However, I think your teacher wanted you to be aware of the "idiom" of `abs(x - y) <= z` for "x is within z of y", because this won't be the last time you ever see it, either in software or in math.  In fact, you'll see `|x-y|<z` in math *a lot* in certain subjects; for example, here's an article on [epsilon-delta proofs](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Epsilon-DeltaProof.html).

I think the code I wrote is more Pythonic. That said, you need to look at the code your teacher described and be able to instantly recognize it as the same thing as `|x-y|<z`, no matter which way it's written.